# Why does imovie freeze everytime I select videos from iphoto in the events library?

Tags: updates, freeze, iphoto, imovie

I am trying to use imovie to make a movie and it used to work perfectly for me. I haven't used it in a while and I have added some new photos and videos to iphoto since the last time that I used it. My problem is, whenever I click on iphoto videos in the events bar I get a loading spinwheel that lasts forever. Are there any solutions out there to this? If I just import one or two videos from my collection the program works fine, but as soon as I attempt to see my iphoto video collection in the event tab, it freezes.

Comment: It's "just works"ing, leave it alone for a few minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have too much footage in your iphoto library for imovie to handle. I had that same problem, and I don't think my computer's ram could handle it. I copied a lot of the iphoto videos to an external folder (just in case) and then moved those same videos to my iphoto trash can (they're still in the application) and then they don't show up in the imovie application anymore..

Now, it works fine. I have about an hour and a half of footage for the imovie thumbnails.